# Tweepy retrieve tweet text and attached image url

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get, for a list of a tweets with a media attached and with a specific hashtag, their:
text, author id, tweet id, creation data, retweet_count, like_count and image url.

I am, however, having some problem grabbing the image url of the media attachment.
This is one of my very poor (quite the novice here) attempts to do it:

```py
client = tweepy.Client('bearer_token')

response = client.search_recent_tweets(
                "#covid -is:retweet has:media", 
                max_results=100,
                expansions="author_id,attachments.media_keys",
                tweet_fields="created_at,public_metrics,attachments",
                user_fields="username,name,profile_image_url",
                media_fields="public_metrics,url,height,width,alt_text")
  

for tweet in response.data:
    metric = tweet.public_metrics
    print(f"{tweet.created_at}, {tweet.text}, {tweet.author_id} \n {metric['retweet_count']}, {metric['like_count']}")
    for image in tweet.includes['media']:
        media[image.media_key] = f"{image.url}"
        print(media[image.media_key])
```

With this I can get the text of the tweet. If I use the same technique with Paginator to obtain more tweets I cannot even see the text....

Anyone knows how to retrieve both the text and the image url (preferably using Paginator) of a tweet ?